# Python Multiprocessing - is this method a valid way to configure and access process values in a safe way?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is the below strategy a satisfactory way to spawn several new processes with their own multiprocessing value variable for later access in a process safe manner? Can each of the processes write to the process_outputs list independently and asynchronously? It seems to work but I have not seen this method used.

```
def process_function(output):
  do something
  output.value = something

if __name__ == '__main__':
  processes = []
  process_outputs=[]
  for i in range(num_processes):
      process_outputs.append(mp.Value('l', 0))
      processes.append(mp.Process(target=process_function, args=(process_outputs[i])))
  for process in processes:
      process.start()
  for process in processes:
      process.join()
  for j in range(num_processes):
      if process_outputs[j].value == something:
          pass  # do something
      else:
          pass  # do something else
```

Comment: Are you asking how to safely collect the return values of multiple processes? You seem to want to call `process_function` a certain number of times, and instead of returning a value, you appear to be setting some value. However, the end result appears to be "run a bunch of functions in parallel and collect the return values"?

Comment: You 'join' all the processes before using the results, so where in your example is the "asynchronous" part? Do you need access to the return values of functions completing sooner before the other functions complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just want to collect return values of functions that run in parallel. That can be done much simpler:

```
import multiprocessing


def process_function(n):
    return n ** 2  # just computing a square for example


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    results = pool.map(process_function, data)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(results)
```

If you somehow need access to the results as they become available, instead of waiting for all the functions to complete:

```
import multiprocessing
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time


def process_function(n):
    start = time()
    sleep(d := randint(1, 5))
    return n, n ** 2, d, start  # a tuple of n, its square, delay and start time


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_function, data):
        print(result)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Example output:

```
(2, 4, 1, 1688715880.890775)
(1, 1, 1, 1688715880.888705)
(3, 9, 3, 1688715880.9089909)
(5, 25, 3, 1688715880.9211953)
(4, 16, 5, 1688715880.9120545)
```

This shows that the inputs are processed in parallel and that the results are processed as soon as they become available. The timestamp shows that all calls were started within moments of each other, the delay shows that they indeed complete in the expected order.

This example doesn't act differently depending on the returned result, it just prints all of them, but it's of course trivial to replace the call to `print()` with something more clever.

Edit: keep in mind that this is just an example, kept brief for simplicity. As pointed out in the comments, you'll want to ensure your code doesn't hang if there's the possibility of exceptions in the called function (hardly the case here) by using a context manager like this (also obviating the need to join and close the pool):

```
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_function, data):
            print(result)
```

There's more things to add and say here, but that goes well beyond the context of the question.

Comment: `with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool` – this would leave the pool hanging if there's an exception.

Comment: There's many things to add here for code that's ready for actual use - I wanted to limit the code to what is relevant to he problem OP is asking to solve. You're right though, adding a context manager is a good idea. (I've added a bit to the answer to that effect, but I think the original example is better left simple)

Comment: Using the context manager would make the original examples shorter too, as you don't need to close and join by hand.

Comment: That's a good point and I've removed the superfluous commands from the example at the end. However, shorter isn't always better. You're right in pointing out that the context manager does that job - but unless that's explicitly pointed out, it may not be obvious and from OP's code, it's clear that they are not aware of context managers (they didn't even close the pool)

Comment: It's not only about brevity with `with`, it's about correctness. You (hopefully) wouldn't tell anyone to use `f = open(...)`without closing the file; you'd tell them to use `with open(...) as f`?

Comment: @AKX perhaps you're just someone looking to be right on the internet, but I think it's pretty clear from my comments what I'm saying, and what you seem to be ignoring. Teaching someone or answering a question isn't helped by bothering them with other aspects of a problem, regardless of whether those aspects are true or important. I would never use that code without a context manager. But that's not the point. OP asked a specific question - I answered the specific question. You're just making a point about something that really has no bearing on the problem presented and the question asked.

Comment: No, I'm not someone looking to be right &c., but in brief: OP isn't using `mp.Pool`, you're telling them to use `mp.Pool`, but your examples use it in a non-idiomatic/error-prone way. Since OP presumably didn't know anything about `mp.Pool`, wouldn't it be better to just teach them to use it idiomatically/less error-pronely, while you're already teaching them about the new concepts?